# Anaconda で pyqt4 をインストールしたが ImportError: No module named PyQt4 が出る

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, pyqt, pyenv

明らかにPyQt4がありそうに見えるのに no module が出て困っています。
pip list にはpyqt4はありません。
conda listにはあります。

```
hogenoMacBook-puro:~ hoge$ pyuic4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hoge/.pyenv/versions/anaconda-4.0.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/uic/pyuic.py", line 26, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtCore
ImportError: No module named PyQt4
```

**実行環境**
mac
Python 2.7.3
Anaconda 4.0.0

Comment: 関連性の有無は不明ですが、この記事が参考になるかも。[How to install PyQt4 in anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21637922/9014308)

Comment: ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

追記
以下で解決しました。ありがとうございます。

```
$ conda install pyqt=4 
$ export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/.pyenv/versions/anaconda-4.0.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```